# Wordpress login and redirect after registration / elementor form

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I make an action to map an elementor form widget with registration form with and i want after resgistration the user to be redirected in a specific link and login but my code does not work. When i submit the form the user creted but i get a parserror.

Any options?

Form code:

```
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record',  'elementor_form_create_new_user' , 10, 2 );
function elementor_form_create_new_user($record,$ajax_handler)
{

    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings('form_name');
    //Check that the form is the "create new user form" if not - stop and return;
    if ('Create New User' !== $form_name) {
        return;
    }
    $form_data = $record->get_formatted_data();
    $username = $form_data['Username']; //Get the value of the input with the label "User Name"
    $password = $form_data['Password']; //Get the value of the input with the label "Password"
    $email = $form_data['Email'];  //Get the value of the input with the label "Email"
    $user = wp_create_user($username, $password, $email); // Create a new user, on success return the user_id no failure return an error object
    if (is_wp_error($user)) { // if there was an error creating a new user
        $ajax_handler->add_error_message("Failed to create new user: " . $user->get_error_message()); //add the message
        $ajax_handler->is_success = false;
        return;
    }
    $first_name = $form_data["First Name"]; //Get the value of the input with the label "First Name"
    $last_name = $form_data["Last Name"]; //Get the value of the input with the label "Last Name"
    $address = $form_data["Address"];
    $zip_code = $form_data["Zip Code"];
    $city = $form_data["City"];
    $country = $form_data["Country"];
    $state = $form_data["State"];
    $plus18 = $form_date["18plus"];
    $rights = $form_data["Rights"];

    wp_update_user(array(
        "ID" => $user,
        "first_name" => $first_name,
        "last_name" => $last_name)); // Update the user with the first name and last name
```

Login & Redirect:

```
// Login after registration

function automatically_log_me_in( $user_id ) {
    wp_set_current_user( $user_id);
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
    wp_redirect( home_url( '/register/snfl-membership/' ) );
    exit();
}

automatically_log_me_in($user);
```

When i submit the form the user creted but i get a parserror.

Answer (score 0):

Use Elementor Pro form, then on Actions After Submit add action to Redirect.

Edit Form > Actions After Submit > Add Action > Redirect.

Add this script on your theme functions.php file.

```js
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record',  'ssky_elementor_form_create_new_user' , 10, 2 );

function ssky_elementor_form_create_new_user($record,$ajax_handler)
    {
        $form_name = $record->get_form_settings('form_name');
        //Check that the form is the "create new user form" if not - stop and return;
        if ('Create New User' !== $form_name) {
            return;
        }
        $form_data = $record->get_formatted_data();
        $username=$form_data['Username']; //Get the value of the input with the label "User Name"
        $password = $form_data['Password']; //Get the value of the input with the label "Password"
        $cpassword = $form_data['Confirm Password']; //Get the value of the input with the label "Password"
        $email=$form_data['Email'];  //Get the value of the input with the label "Email"
        
        if($password != $cpassword){
            $error_message = "Confirm password doesn't match password";
            $ajax_handler->add_error_message("Failed to create new user: " . $error_message); //add the message
            $ajax_handler->is_success = false;
            return;
        }
            
        if(username_exists($username)) {
            $error_message = 'Username already existing! please try new one.';
            $ajax_handler->add_error_message("Failed to create new user: " . $error_message); //add the message
            $ajax_handler->is_success = false;
            return;
        }
        
        if(email_exists($email)) {
            $error_message = 'Email already existing! please try new one.';
            $ajax_handler->add_error_message("Failed to create new user: " . $error_message); //add the message
            $ajax_handler->is_success = false;
            return;
        }

        $user_id = wp_create_user($username,$password,$email); // Create a new user, on success return the user_id no failure return an error object
        wp_set_current_user($user_id); // set the current wp user
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id); // start the cookie for the current registered user
    }
```